# Send message from a client on lion to a server on windows

Tags: macos, delphi, client, osx-lion

I would like to send text from my mac lion host to my windows 7 guest os which is running in a vm. I do have a client and a server application running on my windows 7 so it can listen for messages. Now if only I could have a mac client send a message to my server running on my windows vm. Reason why I would like to message my windows vm is because windows is my main development platform.

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: Why not just use a DataSnap service? Which version of Delphi are you using?

Answer (score 3):

You can use standard RPC communication.

Potential techniques are:

- TCP/IP packets (both Windows and Mac support those);
- HTTP messages;
- DataSnap messages;
- RemObjects messages (match your need, but expensive).

For messages, prefer a textual content (e.g. using XML or JSON) to be consumed from Mac, then you can serve the content via a RESTful server, using *Indy* for instance. HTTP is therefore a good idea. Do not use binary format, unless it is perfectly known on Mac. For another implementation possibility, you can see this [sample code using some low-level stuff of mORMot](http://synopse.info/fossil/dir?name=SQLite3/Samples/13%20-%20StandAlone%20JSON%20SQL%20server), including fast http.sys server and JSON process from a DB.

But without knowing how your Mac client should be written (Delphi 2007 did not allow compilation for Mac), it is not possible to determine a precise solution.

Comment: Good answer. There are probably a few more options, but I think you covered the most sane ones :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Lazarus IDE (Free Pascal) to write the client for Mac; the code is very close to Delphi code. You would have to use Synapse as http/tcp-ip library.